# Can anyone explain this algorithm please?

Tags: java, algorithm, sockets

I saw this in many examples in a book I am reading, but the author is not explaining what the algorithm is? String host = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "localhost";

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String host = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "localhost";//This is the part that I don't get
    for (int i = 1; i < 1024; i++) {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket(host, i);
            System.out.println("There is a server on port " + i + " of "
                    + host);
            s.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
            break;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // must not be a server on this port
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Google Java ternary operator

Comment: I did not even know what they were called thanks

Comment: No problem. It's hard to look something up if you don't know what it's called.

Comment: Wait. Before googling it, can you try and *guess* what it means? If you can't guess, can you try and figure it out? What the value of `host` is when you run this program with an argument? How about whithout one?

Comment: mostly id did not undrestand the "?" and the localhost part. I did not know what they were

Comment: As an aside the documentation recommends passing `null` to get the loop-back address rather than `"localhost"`.

Comment: Maybe he (or rather the author of the book this is lifted from) is not looking for a loopback ... Testing for open ports on a loopback interface seems a little ... pointless :)

Comment: @Dima : If he is then he's going a weird way about it. "localhost" will almost certainly resolve to the loopback address in the hosts file (or equivalent) of almost all machines. However someone might interfere with the configuration and the recommended method is to use `null` though I don't guarantee that the source for Socket doesn't substitute a lookup of 'localhost'... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: @DanAllen, if it "almost certainly" resolves to loopback, then it does not matter if you use it instead of null. The only difference is that null *always* resolves to loopback, which `localhost` can resolve to whatever you want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line you commented on sets the `host` String to the first command line argument or `"localhost"` if no command line arguments were present.

It uses the *ternary operator* which basically expands as follows:

```
String host;

if (args.length > 0){
   host = args[0];
}else{
   host = "localhost";
}
```